# jQuery stops working after AJAX is called

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having a bit of trouble with jQuery & ajax on a form. I am using the following snippet to toggle a "checked" class on a radio button so I can change the background colour.

```html
<script>
jQuery(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
        $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).next().removeClass('checked');
        $(this).next().toggleClass('checked', this.checked)
    })
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

This snippet works fine initially, however the form I am using uses ajax and the jQuery stops working after it is called.

I am hoping somebody can help out.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean the form uses ajax? does the ajax response replace the form or edit your radio button, and with that your jQuery code will also be replaced and you have to change your logic or reapply the code.

Comment: Are you creating elements using `$.ajax()`?

Comment: The form is split up into four sections, each section is dynamically loaded with ajax. The snippet works on the first section, however moving onto section two, three and four it does not. I need to find a way for it to work across all sections. I am not creating elements with $.ajax.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/ is what you're looking for id bet. The dynamic stuff needs to have a parent handler.. not something loaded with it.. so when you're loading the controls on the page, you have a `on` with a selector hooked up already that handles the event on the parent.

Comment: read the section on "direct and delegated" events in the link JF gave above. Basically your new elements do not have a "change" event bound to them, because they didn't exist when the event handler was declared. At the moment you execute that code to create the event handler, it goes and attaches itself to all the elements it can find at that moment which match the selector. Any elements which match the selector but are added later don't get bound, because the handler never runs again. Using delegated events is a pretty standard way to get round this

Comment: So to be clear, nothing is "stopping working", you just haven't got anything which is meant to execute

Answer (score 0):

So thanks for pointing me in the right direction and explaining.

I have modified my snippet to the following and it now works as expected:

```html
<script>
$(document).on('click', function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
        $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).next().removeClass('checked');
        $(this).next().toggleClass('checked', this.checked)
    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this format for change event :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("change","input[type='radio']",function () {
    $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).next().removeClass('checked');
    $(this).next().toggleClass('checked', this.checked);
});
</script>
```